# Форма регистрации (PHP)

Tags: регистрация

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема.
Есть сайт доски обьявлений.
В нем все публикации ведутся без регистрации, т.е человек пришел, заполнил форму, подтвердил емайл, и обьявление ушло в прув админу.

Проблема в том, что эта не цмс какой-либо доски или знаменитого движка CMS типа Wordpress, а простая самописная CMS.

Вопрос в том как правильно и лучше интегрировать форму регистрации ? Есть какие то уже готовые решения, или нужно писать на чистом php+mysql ? исходя из структуры ?

Т.е если мне нужно будет писать все на php + mysql хотел бы узнать что лучше взять за базу ? т.е есть ли готовое решение на базе которого можно интегрировать в сайт, а потом уже допилить то что не хватает ?

Идея создания формы возникла за надобностью показывать пользователям сколько обьявлений они запостили, сколько было просмотров, обращений в форму контактов. Т.е что то типа панели статистики.

Comment: Если самописная CMS, то и добавление функционала придётся писать самим. Можно использовать готовые шаблоны из сети с примерами кода, но в любом случае потребуется адаптация под вашу CMS.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth

Comment: Очень неточный вопрос. Что передается? В каких объемах? Какие ожидаемые нагрузки на БД? Без этих ответов посоветовать как тип, так и стр-ру БД сложно. К тому же при желании выбрать "сколько" нужно добавлять индексы. Что нужно индексировать? - Толпа вопросов... Уточните задачу

Comment: Цмс не моя, по разбору полетов, понял что нужно будет создавать дополнительные поля в регистрации, по мимо емайла, пароля, нужно будет создавать так же айди пользователя, по которому и будет идти привязка обьявлений, т.е в базе будет что то типа показать все обьявления если айди такой-то. Регистрация должна быть самой простой, логин, имя,фамилия, тел, пароль. Я просто изначально думал можно что то готовое интегрировать, но понял что там все очень индивидуально..

Comment: Тут неплохая статья "Как написать свой движок блога" с примерами и исходниками, с одним классом user https://daveismyname.blog/blog/creating-a-blog-from-scratch-with-php . А в остальном все действительно индивидуально.